# Snake Java Problems with growth, movement and collisions

Tags: java, user-interface, collision, move

I have been working on a game of snake for quite a while, but have run into many issues with movement, snake growth, and collisions. I would appreciate it if you could help debug my code. My current issue is that the snake movements are awkward and isn't moving up/down/right/left one space at a time.Although the body of the snake should follow the previous segment, the snake isn't doing that. In addition, my snake's growth(once it eats food) always results in strange gaps in the snake's body. Finally, my snake always seems to have problems when colliding with the borders, itself, and food. I am still very new to Java and I have really bad style. Also, this is my first experiment with using GUIs. Thank you all so much!

Here is the snake class:

```
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class snake extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static int points = 0;
    public static int direction;
    public static int delay = 50 ;
    public static int rfood;
    public static int cfood;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> X = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> Y = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int length;
    public static Timer timer;
    public static boolean run = false;



    snake() {
        addKeyListener(new KEY());
        setFocusable(true);
        setSize(800, 800);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
        setVisible(true);
        startGame();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        if (run == true) {
            drawFood(g);
            drawSnake(i, g);


        }
        else{
            GameOver(g);
        }
    }


    public void drawSnake(int i, Graphics s) {
        s.setColor(Color.yellow);
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                s.fillRect(bodyX.get(i), bodyY.get(i), 20, 20);
            }

    }

    public void drawFood(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        gA.fillRect(cf, rf, 20, 20);
    }

    public void GameOver(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("Game Over", 300, 300);
    }

    public static void snakePosition() {
        X.clear();
        Y.clear();
        run = true;
        length = 2;
        X.add(20);
        Y.add(20);
        X.add(30);
        Y.add(20);
    }

    public static void placeFood() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int r = rand.nextInt(19) * 40;
        int c = rand.nextInt(19) * 40;
        while ((r == Y.get(0)) && (c == X.get(0))) {
            r = rand.nextInt(19) * 40;
            c = rand.nextInt(19) * 40;
        }
        rfood = r;
        cfood = c;
    }

    public static void collision() {
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            if ((X.get(0) == X.get(i) && (Y.get(0) == Y.get(i)))) {
                points = 0;
                snakePosition();
            }
        }

        if ((X.get(0) > 800) || (X.get(0) < 0) || (Y.get(0) > 800) || (Y.get(0) < 0)) {
            points = 0;
            resetSnakePosition();

        }
    }

    public static void collideFood() {
        if ((X.get(0) == cfood) && (Y.get(0) == rfood)) {

            X.add(0);
            Y.add(0);
            points++;
            length++;
            placeFood();
        }
    }



    public static void move() {
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
            X.set(i + 1, X.get(i));
            Y.set(i + 1, Y.get(i));
            if (direction == 0) {
                Y.set(0, Y.get(0) - 20);
            }
            if (direction == 1) {
                X.set(0, X.get(0) + 20);
            }

            if (direction == 2) {
                Y.set(0, Y.get(0) + 20);
            }
            if (direction == 3) {
                X.set(0, X.get(0) - 20);

            }


        }

    }



    public void startGame() {
        placeFood();
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (run == true) {
            collideFood();
            move();
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        snakePosition();
        new snake();
    }

}
```

Here is my KEY class:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class KEY extends KeyAdapter {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) || (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)) {
            if (snake.direction != 2) {
                snake.direction = 0;
            }
        }
        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) || (key == KeyEvent.VK_D)) {
            if (snake.direction != 3) {
                snake.direction = 1;
            }
        }
        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) || (key == KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
            if (snake.direction != 0) {
                snake.direction = 2;
            }
        }
        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) || (key == KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
            if (snake.direction != 1) {
                snake.direction = 3;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Let me summarize: it cannot move, it cannot eat, it cannot grow, it cannot detect collisions, and it is not drawn correctly (gaps). Suppose that we throw out all the parts that are broken, what exactly will remain? Your copyright notice? Please reduce the problem until you obtain an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It can move and eat. However, when it eats it grows weird. Also, it can detect collisions, but sometimes it glitches out. I'm sorry if my post was confusing, but I appreciate the comment.

Comment: On a less ironical note: as it is, it's a [ball-of-mud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud). Separate the logical representation (proper grid, all steps +1, -1, not +20) from the graphical representation. Make sure it paints a motionless snake correctly. Separate motion from collisions. Make sure that motion works before you tackle collisions. Split collisions into three separate classes (wall, self-collision, fruit-collision), make sure they all work separately before you combine them. Never expose unnecessary details to classes that don't need them.

Comment: And don't cram everything into a single file. It's unnecessary, and it only makes it harder for you, because it distracts and forces you to scroll over currently irrelevant parts of the program all the time. You can't accidentally fix all problems of your program at once, especially if every part affects every other part. Subdivide the problem into manageable pieces. You can really easily separate motion from collisions. Write a ghost-snake on infinite plane that can go through itself first, then add the "growing", then collisions. Divide-and-conquer!